# How to update iOS app over the network

Tags: iphone, ios

I've created a simple iOS app that allows people to place order for goods.  For example, a user would open the app and see a list (`UITableView`) of items that they can purchase such as a textbook or a calculator.

Right now, the items that are shown are obtained from an `xml` file such as this one

```
<item>
    <name>Calculator</name>
    <price>7.22</price>
</item>
...
```

My question is, **what technologies would I need to use so that I could make small changes this xml file remotely without having to resubmit to the App store.**  For example, suppose a calculator now costs 8.00 rather than 7.22.  Or maybe I need to make the entire word `Calculator` uppercase.

I'm thinking of some sort of server that the app could connect to and then download the xml file from; however, I have absolutely no idea how to get started on this.

Keep in mind that I don't have any hardware of my own (meaning I don't have a server computer in my basement) and all I need to be able to do is update the xml file.  I'm looking for the simples (and cheapest) way possible to acomplish this.

Suggestions? Guidance? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could upload your XML file to Amazon S3 and make it public. That is probably one of the cheapest options for the server side.

As for the client side, there are different ways to fetch the file. This is a simple way:

```
NSString *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL of the xml file"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

From there, you can parse it as an XML file.

There are also other networking libraries that depending on what you want to do, might make it easier for you. Some examples of these libraries are [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit), [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit).

Comment: Wow...That was so easy, I still can't believe it